# Find $a,b$, such that $x^4+4x^3+4x^2+a= 0$ and $x^3+x^2-x+b=0$ have one common double root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Given $x^4+4x^3+4x^2+a =0$ and $x^3+x^2-x+b=0$, how can I approach finding $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ knowing those two polynomials have a common double root?

So far, what I have tried is using Viete's relations, but the system of equations I reached doesn't seem helpful at all without knowing anything else about the roots themselves. Dividing both by $(x-\alpha)^2$, where $\alpha$ is the common root, leads me to a true statement, but it is a dead-end as far as I can tell. What would be a complete proof for the values of $a$ and $b$ without guessing them (mentioning this because the workbook's multiple answers all have $-2 \le a,b \le 2)$? Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to find $a$ such that the first equation has a double root?

Comment: Hint: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, $\alpha$ is a double root of $f(x)=0 \implies f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=0$ .

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, I think it can have a real double root. Following Li Kwok Keung's hint and letting $g(x)=x^3+x^2-x+b$, with $\alpha$ being its double root, doing $g(\alpha) = 0 \iff (\alpha+1)(\alpha-\frac{1}{3})=0$, so the double root can be $-1$ or $\frac{1}{3}$. Now let $f$ be the first polynomial containing $a$, and combining what we learneda about $\alpha$, $f'(\alpha)=(\alpha+1)\alpha(\alpha+2) = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = -1$. Then I just substitute $x$ with $\alpha$ in both polynomials and find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This returns $a=b=-1$ which is indeed the right solution according to my book. Thank you all so much for the help! Seeing the proof now, it really is a basic problem I should've been able to solve.

Answer (score 1):

By the comments, or by writing the cubic polynomial as $(x-c)^2(x-d)$ we see that $c$ is a double root of $x^3+x^2-x+b$ if and only if $3c^2+2c-1=0$, i.e., if
$$
c=-1 \text{ or } c=\frac{1}{3},
$$
with $b= c^2(2c + 1)$. For $c=1$ we obtain $b=-1$ and
$$
x^3+x^2-x+b=(x+1)^2(x-1)
$$
Taking the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) with $x^4+4x^3+4x^2+a$ gives
$$
(a + 9)(a + 1)^2=0.
$$
For $a=-1$ we have indeed
$$
x^4+4x^3+4x^2+a=(x^2 + 2x - 1)(x + 1)^2
$$

Similarly we can treat the case $c=\frac{1}{3}$, where there is no solution. Indeed, we obtain $b=-\frac{5}{27}$ and $(81a + 49)(81a + 25)=0$, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: "... we know that [a root] $c$ is a double ..."

Answer (score 0):

An approach can be the following:

A (unitary) polynomial of degree $4$ with a double root is of kind $(x^2+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)^2$ whilst a (unitary) polynomial of degree $3$ with a double root is of kind $(x-\beta_1)(x-\beta_2)^2$.

But now

$$(x^2+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)^2=(x^2+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2)(x^2-2\alpha_3x+\alpha_3^2)=x^4+(-2\alpha_3-\alpha_1)x^3+(\alpha_3^2-2\alpha_3\alpha_1+\alpha_2)x^2+(\alpha_1\alpha_3^2-2\alpha_3\alpha_2)x+\alpha_2\alpha_3^2$$

and

$$(x-\beta_1)(x-\beta_2)^2=(x-\beta_1)(x^2-2\beta_2x+\beta_2^2)=x^3+(-2\beta_2-\beta_1)x^2+(\beta_2^2+2\beta_1\beta_2)x-\beta_1\beta_2^2$$

Now you have to impose that $k:=\alpha_3=\beta_2$... can you continue now?

Answer (score 0):

We can also examine the properties of the function curves for $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x^2 + a \  $ and $ \ g(x) \ = \ x^3 + x^2 - x + b \ \ . \ $  In order for these functions to share a "double zero", they must have a "turning point" (which becomes a "touching" $ \ x-$intercept) in common.  Since the quartic polynomial has at most three turning points and the cubic polynomial at most two, there is a rather limited set of possibilities for solutions to the question.

It can be useful to investigate the "depressed" polynomials if we wish to avoid applying calculus or making a graph of the curves; these have the potential of revealing symmetries of the original polynomials by "horizontally shifting" their function curves.  For $ \ g(x) \ , \ $ we have
$$ g \left( x - \frac13 \right) \ \ \stackrel {\zeta \ = \ x \ - \ 1/3} {\longrightarrow} \ \ g(\zeta) \ \ = \ \ \zeta^3 \ - \ \frac43·\zeta \ + \ \left( \ b \ + \ \frac{11}{27} \ \right) \ \ , $$
and for $ \ f(x) \ , $
$$ f( x - 1 ) \ \ \stackrel {\xi \ = \ x \ - \ 1} {\longrightarrow} \ \ f(\xi) \ \ = \ \ \xi^4 \ - \ 2·\xi^2 \ + \ ( \ a \ + \ 1 \ ) \ \ . $$

The transformed quartic polynomial is a biquadratic, which we will find easier to work with (the transformed cubic is more difficult to analyze without calculus).  We can see that with $ \ a \ = \ -1 \ \ , \ $ this function becomes $ \  \xi^4  -  2·\xi^2 \ = \  \xi^2·(\xi^2  -  2) \ = \ \xi^2·(\xi   +  \sqrt2)·(\xi  -  \sqrt2) \ \ , \ $ so it has a double zero at $ \ \xi \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ which tells us that $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x^2 - 1 \  $ has a double zero at $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ \ . \ $  It is also clear that $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ $ produces the "binomial-square"  $ \  \xi^4  -  2·\xi^2 + 1 \ = \   (\xi^2  -  1)^2 \ = \  (\xi   +  1)^2·(\xi   -  1)^2 \ \ , \ $ which has double zeroes at $ \ \xi \ = \ -1 \ \rightarrow \ x \ = \ -2 \ $ and $ \ \xi \ = \ +1 \ \rightarrow \ x \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  This accounts for the maximum possible number of turning points for $ \ f(x) \  : \ $  there are just three "candidate" shared double-zeroes, $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ , \ 0 \ \ [ \ a \ = \ 0 \ ] \ \ ; \ \ x \ = \ -1 \ \ [ \ a \ = \ -1 \ ] \ \ . $

For the cubic polynomial, we can now make use of your intended approach using the Viete relations.  Since we seek a value for $ \ b \ $ that gives $ \ g(x) \ $ a double zero, which we'll call $ \ r \ \ $ (we'll call the remaining real zero $ \ s \ \ ) \ , $ we find
$$ -(2r \ + \ s) \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ \ , \ \ \ -r^2·s \ \ = \ \ b \ \ \ , \ \ \ \frac{r·r \ + \ 2·r·s}{r^2·s} \ \ = \ \ \frac{-1}{-b} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{2}{r} \ + \ \frac{1}{s} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{b}  \ \ .  $$

We then "test" the three candidates for a common double zero:

• $ \ \ r \ = \ -2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -4 + s \ = \ -1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ s \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -(-2)^2·3 \ \ = \ \ -12 \ \ , \ \ \frac{2}{-2} \ + \ \frac{1}{3} \ \ \neq \ \ \frac{1}{-12}  \ \ \  $ [not consistent] ;

• $ \ \ r \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 0 + s \ = \ -1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ s \ = \ -1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -0^2·(-1) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , \ \ \frac{2}{0} \ + \ \frac{1}{-1} \ \ \neq \ \ \frac{1}{0}  \ \ \  $ [reject] ;

• $ \ \ r \ = \ -1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -2 + s \ = \ -1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ s \ = \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -(-1)^2·1 \ \ = \ \ -1 \ \ , \ \ \frac{2}{-1} \ + \ \frac{1}{1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{-1}  $      **[consistent]**    .

So there is only one such pair of polynomials,
$$ x^4 \ + \ 4x^3 \ + \ 4x^2 \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ (x + 1)^2·(x^2 + 2x - 1) \ \ = \ \ (x + 1)^2·(x -  1 - \sqrt2)·(x -  1 + \sqrt2)  $$
and
$$ x^3 \ + \ x^2  \ - \ x \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ (x + 1)^2·(x  - 1) \ \ ,  $$
with $ \ \mathbf{ a \ = \ b \ = \ -1 } \ \ . $

[image]